# Issue when unit testing a service using Thymeleaf template Engine

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I got a nullPointerException when unit testing my service and i do not understand why? I m using Spring boot.
This is my simple service which provide Templating. I autowired TemplateEngine Component.

```
@Service
public class TicketTemplatingService implements ITemplatingService{

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    /**
     * This method will return a ticket template
     */
    @Override
    public String buildHtmlTemplating(Object object, String templateName) {
        Ticket ticket= (Ticket)object;
        //Build the template
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("id", ticket.getId());
        context.setVariable("date", ticket.getDate());        
        return  templateEngine.process(templateName, context);
    }

}
```

The unit test of this class is below:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TemplatingServiceTest {


    @InjectMocks
    private TicketTemplatingService ticketTemplatingService;

    @Mock
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHtmlTemplateReturnTheHtmlTemplate(){
        Ticket ticket= new Ticket();
        ticket.setId(1L);
        Date date=new Date();
        ticket.setDate(date);

        Context context=new Context();
        context.setVariable("id", 1L);
        context.setVariable("date", date);

        //Mock the process method of the templateEngine bean
        when(templateEngine.process("TemplateName", refEq(context))).thenReturn("Html template result");

        //Now we can test the method
        String htmlTemplate=ticketTemplatingService.buildHtmlTemplating(ticket, "TemplateName");
        assertThat(htmlTemplate).isEqualTo("Html template result");
    }
}
```

In this test class, the templateEngine variable mocked return null, and then i got nullPointerException when doing this "when(templateEngine.process("TemplateName", refEq(context))).thenReturn("Html template result");"

Please can you help me? i really do not unsderstand why.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of

```
@Autowired
private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
```

use this interface in your Service.

```
import org.thymeleaf.ITemplateEngine;

@Autowired
private ITemplateEngine templateEngine;
```

And in your test class use same class as a Mock

```
@Mock
private ITemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine;

@Before
public void setup(){
    @when(emailTemplateEngine.process(eq(TEMPLATE_USER_CREATION), any(Context.class))).thenReturn(userCreationHtml);
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Comment: upvoted. Would you provide the reason why Interface?

Comment: That won't work as in mockito you are not able to test final methods and process() of TemplateEngine is final

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same issue as you while testing thymeleaf template using Mokito. Based on my research, you may want to try:

1. check the version of your Thymeleaf jar. If you use the spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependecny, it might still use version < 3.0, which is older than the current stable version.

According to this link: [Final methods in TemplateEngine make it difficult to mock](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/314)
The 3.0 version has better solution for such issue.

If you are using 3.0+ version, then PowerMock can come to rescue. 
Refer to this link: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockfinal
for how to mock final method (This link uses EasyMock)

If you are using < 3.0 version, as of now, the only temporary fix I found is the last comment from the first link in the post.

Good luck with your research and wish more talent can come to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

How @Mengru said, Mockito has issues with final classes and methods, but that is solved with a simple configuration file: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final. I don't know if this file has any implications or issues, you could give a try.

Or how @Mengru and @cazador said, in version 3.0+ you could replace it with the interface `ITemplateEngine`.